# deno bundle - Property 'gpu' does not exist on type 'Navigator' [TS2339]

Tags: typescript, deno, webgpu

Update (2024/03/06): [Experimental WebGPU support has been re-enabled in Deno 1.39](https://deno.com/blog/v1.39#webgpu-is-back). This issue still persists for me - what's the solution?

---

In Deno 1.8, [unstable/experimental support for WebGPU was added](https://deno.com/blog/v1.8#experimental-support-for-the-webgpu-api).

With WebGPU landing in Chrome Stable 113, I decided it was about time I start my foray into graphics programming. I do understand that [no other browser](https://caniuse.com/webgpu) has this feature enabled by default (yet).

Here is a basic example I tried getting up and running (stolen from their announcement):

```js
// Try to get an adapter from the user agent.
const adapter = await navigator.gpu.requestAdapter();
if (adapter) {
  // Print out some basic details about the adapter.
  const adapterInfo = await adapter.requestAdapterInfo();

  // On some systems this will be blank...
  console.log(`Found adapter: ${adapterInfo.device}`);

  // Print GPU feature list
  const features = [...adapter.features.values()];
  console.log(`Supported features: ${features.join(", ")}`);
} else {
  console.error("No adapter found");
}
```

Here is the command I'm using to bundle my code: `deno bundle --config deno.jsonc ui/static/script/run.ts bin/static/script/run.js`

And here is the associated `deno.jsonc` (make note - I'm targeting the browser):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "dom.iterable",
            "dom.asynciterable",
            "deno.ns"
        ]
    },
    "unstable": [
        "webgpu"
    ],
    "lint": {
        "include": [
            "ui/static/script/"
        ]
    },
    "fmt": {
        "include": [
            "ui/static/script/"
        ],
        "lineWidth": 120
    },
}
```

When I try bundling this basic example, I get this error:

```
⚠️ Warning: `deno bundle` is deprecated and will be removed in Deno 2.0.
Use an alternative bundler like "deno_emit", "esbuild" or "rollup" instead.
Check file:///<repo>/ui/static/script/run.ts
error: TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'gpu' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.
const adapter = await navigator.gpu.requestAdapter();
                                ~~~
    at file:///<repo>/ui/static/script/run.ts:2:33
```

I've tried a couple things:

1. Adding `--unstable` after `deno bundle`

   - (Yes - I'm aware `deno bundle` may be deprecated soon. The Deno community did not like this decision, and it seems like it is [still up for debate](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/11073#issuecomment-1605918145).)
2. Adding `"unstable": ["webgpu"]` to `deno.jsonc`.

Both of which seem to have zero affect.

How do I get access to WebGPU when developing Typescript with Deno?

Comment: To safely test existence of property use the `in` keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the current time (Deno is at version `1.34.3` as I write this answer), the WebGPU API is not available in Deno.

Here's a chronological list of related events:

- `2020-10-07`: Requested in [denoland/deno#7863](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/7863)
- `2021-03-01`: Implemented in [denoland/deno#7977](https://github.com/denoland/deno/pull/7977)
- `2023-03-16`: Removed in [denoland/deno#18094](https://github.com/denoland/deno/pull/18094)

If you want to follow the status of potential re-implementation, there's an open issue in the related examples repo: [denoland/webgpu-examples#13](https://github.com/denoland/webgpu-examples/issues/13).

---

**Re: Bundling**

You should never bundle code destined for a browser environment using Deno's deprecated built-in bundler tool — [it was never designed to produce code for consumption outside of the Deno runtime](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/11073). (Per the warning you saw — it's deprecated and will be removed, so you really shouldn't be using it anymore at all — it's time to seek an alternative tool.)

Since you might wonder how to proceed with an alternative — here's a suggestion: Luca (Deno core team) maintains [`esbuild_deno_loader`](https://github.com/lucacasonato/esbuild_deno_loader), which is a plugin I've used successfully with [`esbuild`](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild) to bundle Deno TypeScript codebases. Both include usage documentation.

Comment: In the meantime, is there a way to circumvent this? For example, integrate with these NPM Typescript type definitions for WebGPU? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@webgpu/types

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76561043/deno-bundle-property-gpu-does-not-exist-on-type-navigator-ts2339/76564259?noredirect=1#comment135012790_76564259) @goddtriffin If you have a new question, please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the solution might be to manually import the WebGPU types: `import * as _webgpu from "https://esm.sh/@webgpu/types";`.

I have an [open issue with Deno](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/22742) for confirming this solution. Still very curious why I have to manually configure this.